# How to route same web domain in different implementations

Tags: php, python, web-services, apache, flask

Lets suppose i have a domain `www.mydomain.com` and i have an API provider written in python, and a PHP/html website that consumes that API. and all of them uses the same domain.

Ex:

- API: `api.mydomain.com/getfoo`
- PHP: `www.mydomain.com/foo`

i need `api.mydomain.com/getfoo` routes to the python implementation, and `www.mydomain.com/foo` routes to the PHP website.

And all of those two implementations are in different servers.

How to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: what are you using? Django?

Comment: @PurityLake im using flask microframework for api providor

Comment: What's the problem if they're on *different* servers? Just set your DNS to go to right host, no different than saying www.mydomain.com and www2.mydomain.com go to different hosts.